# Deleting slow on X11 emacs

Tags: emacs, xorg

I'm running GNU Emacs 21.4.1  on a (remote) remote Linux ((CentOS) box, using my MacBook as the X-server.  Works fine, unless I try to delete a word, line, or region. Then it locks up for 30 seconds or so.  It sounds like a minor thing, but you realize how often you do a delete when you have to stop for 30 seconds every time.

My theory is that Emacs is trying to put the text in the X-server cut-and-paste buffer, which is trying to put it in the OSX cut-and-paste buffer and somewhere along the way, the process is blocked until it times out.  (My only evidence for this theory is (a) copy-region behaves the same way and (b) deleted text doesn't show up in the buffer.)

Any suggestions appreciated.

**Edit:**

```
 (setq interprogram-cut-function nil)
```

fixed me right up.  Which makes perfect sense.  Thanks, Trey.

Answer (score 3):

I have occasionally had the same problem on my Linux box (using Gnome), and haven't tracked down the ultimate cause.  However, toggling the cut/paste behavior often clears it up.  I've written these two utilities that I run when the problem crops up.  You may find them useful:

```
(defun xor (a b)
  (or (and a (not b)) (and (not a) b)))

(defun reset-cut ()
  "toggle the intprogram cut function to avoid odd x hangup"
  (interactive)
  (message "Cut is %s" (setq interprogram-cut-function (xor interprogram-cut-function 'x-select-text))))

(defun reset-paste ()
  "toggle the intprogram paste function to avoid odd x hangup"
  (interactive)
  (message "Paste is %s" (setq interprogram-paste-function (xor interprogram-paste-function 'x-cut-buffer-or-selection-value))))
```

Comment: No `xor` function for me.  Setting interprogram-cut-function to 'x-select-text` doesn't seem to help.

Comment: @Malvolio I updated the answer to provide xor, and you might need to leave the cut-function as nil for a while.

Comment: Setting the cut-function to nil did it.